# Gel seat modification for KTM Duke 200

Tags: seat, duke, india

I am looking to modify (or seat cover) my KTM 200 seat. I am looking to make my seat (rider and pillon) more comfortable for longer rides above 100km (max I have done is 900km in a day). Could you please suggest some good options? I am based in Pune, India.

Either DIY or some store.

Comment: Unfortunately shopping type questions are off topic for this SE. Perhaps you may be able to modify your question in a way which is not looking for a product, but maybe a better way to fix your issue?

Comment: I have updated the question, please put it off hold